# window phone - How to disable current select item?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone

I have a xaml :

```
<phone:LongListSelector Name="llsSourceNews"  ItemsSource="{Binding SourceNews}">
        <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid x:Name="gridNews">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="80" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="250"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding icon}" Stretch="Fill" Height="35" Width="70"></Image>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="White" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="24" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                    <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Source="/Images/Add-New.png" x:Name="imgAdd"  Tap="imgAdd_Tap"></Image>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector>
```

and tap event :

```
private void imgAdd_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
   {
       if(true)
       {
        this.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
       }
    }
```

My problem is : when user tap image,all image is disable.I want to image is disable which is selected.

Comment: you said that "when user tap image, all image is disable", but I don't see any code disabling any image in the question..

Comment: I'm sorry "this.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;" is visiable Longlistselector.So I want to if user select item and then visiable select item.

Answer (score 1):

`this` in your case refers to the page. If you want to retrieve the image, you have to cast the `sender` parameter:

```
private void imgAdd_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    if(true)
    {
        var element = (FrameworkElement)sender;
        element.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```